When to use QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking in EF Core?
This is more of a general software architecture question. I have an API that is using a DbContext and I was having an issue where I would create a user and subsequent requests to delete the user would be denied because the entity was already being tracked.
I've now added AddScoped() when adding the DbContext, and this has taken care of the subsequent requests issue. In the course of trouble shooting I did add this to the DbContext options:
options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);

I'm wondering if I should keep this option and wanted to get some feedback on how other developers handle this.
I did review the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.usequerytrackingbehavior?view=efcore-8.0
Here it notes the following:
"Disabling change tracking is useful for read-only scenarios because it avoids the overhead of setting up change tracking for each entity instance. You should not disable change tracking if you want to manipulate entity instances and persist those changes to the database using SaveChanges()."
I'm kind of curious on how other developers handle this. Sometimes the repos are only pulling entities from the DbContext and sending them in responses... sometimes they're updating the entities. If there is overhead in tracking the context is there a general performance improvement in setting the default query tracking behavior to .AsNoTracking()? How much overhead is involved in adding only entities I want updated and saved?
Just kind of curious as to how other developers handle this.
I currently have default query behavior set to no tracking and wanted feedback on whether this improves performance.

I don't see no tracking as necessarily being a good solution to your problem (deleting a user being denied because it is being tracked elsewhere) - but it might be. As far as asking if that particular option improves performance you already have the answer in the documentation you found (and the guidance on using it: disabling change tracking is useful for read-only scenarios because it avoids the overhead of setting up change tracking for each entity instance).

I think the docs say it all. "You should not disable change tracking if you want to manipulate entity instances and persist those changes". I don't see what we can add to that. The effect of tracking increases with the amount of tracked entities, exponentially rather than linearly, depending on the relationships, so it's impossible to tell how much overhead is involved. It depends. Possible duplicate.

Only for read-only systems. If you are manipulating data it is far, far more trouble than it is worth. When you are reading large amounts of data like search results, just add AsNoTracking() to those specific queries. (whether reading entities or projections) Opting for no-tracking by default makes updating data very messy when leveraging the benefits of navigation properties. Even with simple entities that have no navigation properties, the difference between change tracking vs. Update() is that Update() always results in an UPDATE SQL statement for every property in the entity (minus PK) where change tracking will only produce an UPDATE statement if at least one property actually changed, and only for the properties that did change.
You can self-manage re-attaching entities from No-Tracking queries, but it is messy, especially when you have navigation properties as you have to go through those one by one and re-attach them all. Even then it's not always a simple re-attachment, you need to check for existing tracked references first and replace references if found, every time, or you get situational runtime exceptions.
My advice when it comes to tuning for performance /w EF:
The biggest factors that affect performance with EF queries would be:

Select N+1: Lazy loading, often caused by serializing entities or general bindings to lazy loaded navigation properties. Avoid by using projections. (.Select())
Missing/poor indexes: Improve by developing with real-world data quality and inspecting queries for index recommendations.
Cartesian Products: Eager loading too much. Can be addressed in EF Core /w .AsSplitQuery(). Also mitigated using projections.
Long-lived DbContext: EF's tracking cache has an inverse relationship with performance. The more entities in the cache the longer reads and inserts take. (Also leads to stale data issues)

When reading swaths of data (search results, reports, etc.) read projections of view models containing only the values you need to display and PK/FKs needed for wiring up requests/actions. When reading projections, still use .AsNoTracking() as while projections do not get added to the tracking cache, EF is still inspecting the projections for entities that might be tracked without it. Also be sure to use server-side pagination.
When updating rows, accept a view model with just the data that should be changed and the PK, fetch the single entity graph and perform the update.
When dealing with updating object graphs (lots of related data to be added/removed/update) design for atomic operations in the application rather than "everything at once". If the changes are best committed all at once consider a status on the row or caching atomic updates to a separate saved state with the commit loading and updating the graph at once.
When reading expensive secondary data as part of large sets that is useful to have on-hand but not a critical part of what users are going to be working with, break those out into asynchronous requests. For instance if there are stats you want to display as part of search results, but they are more informational when users might, or might not need to consider them, loading the results without the stats but rendering a hyperlink to make a quick one-off request for the stats for a selected row rather than incurring the cost across all results every time.
Tune things like search criteria to what users need and use most commonly rather than catering to cover the the most edge cases. Design decisions around enabling flexibility that users rarely use can end up hurting performance. If there is a need for expensive searches, keep that capability separated from what the typical user will be doing.
For really expensive operations like report views which might touch a large volume of data, consider a request queue with background process to handle the requests and report back completion/status rather than attempting per-request processing. Also look at whether these read-only requests could be served by a read-only replica database.
Don't get caught out with thinking EF is a hammer so every problem must be a nail. If you have requirements like bulk inserts or such that there is a better tool to use than EF, then use that tool for that job. Don't confine yourself for the sake of consistency. EF won't get jealous. :)
There are lots of areas in general design and EF specifically that can improve performance, but don't expect silver bullets to deliver a reliable boost. The closest thing to a silver bullet for performance I would recommend is the use of projection in queries. It avoids the risk of Select N+1 and can help minimize Cartesian Product costs.
